# Data recognition, parsing, filtering, and transformation -- GUI?

Tags: python, ruby, perl, kettle, data-manipulation

Looking for a non-cloud based open source app for doing data transformation; though for a killer (and I mean killer) app just built for data transformations, I might be willing to spend up to $1000.

I've looked at [Perl](http://www.manning.com/cross/), [Kapow Katalyst](http://kapowsoftware.com/products/kapow-katalyst-platform/index.php), [Pentaho Kettle](http://kettle.pentaho.com/), and more.

**Perl, Python, Ruby** which are clearly languages, but unable to find any frameworks/DSLs just for processing data; meaning they're really not a great development environments, meaning there's no built GUI's for building RegEx, Input/Output (CSV, XML, JDBC, REST, etc.), no debugger for testing rows and rows of data -- they're not bad either, just not what I'm looking for, which is a GUI built for complex data transformations; that said, I'd love if the GUI/app file was in a scripting language, and NOT just stored in some not human readable XML/ASCII file.

**Kapow Katalyst** is made for accessing data via HTTP (HTML, CSS, RSS, JavaScript, etc.) it's got a nice GUI for transforming unstructured text, but that's not its core value offering, and is way, way too expensive. It does an okay job of traversing document namespace paths; guessing it's just XPath on the back-end, since the syntax appears to be the same.

**Pentaho Kettle** has a nice GUI for INPUT/OUTPUT of most common data stores, and its own take on handling data processing; which is okay, and just has a small learning curve. Kettle's debugger is ok, in that the data is easy to see, but the errors and exceptions are not threaded with the output, and there no way to really debug an issue; meaning you can't reload the output/error/exception, but are able to view the system feedback. All that said, Kettle data transformation is _______ well, let's just say it left me feeling like I must be missing something, because I was completely puzzled by "if it's not possible, just write the transformation in JavaScript"; umm, what?

So, any suggestions? Do realize that I haven't really spec'd out any [**transformations**](http://kapowsoftware.com/products/kapow-katalyst-platform/transformation-normalization.php), but figure if you really use a product for data munging, I'd like to know about it; even excel, I guess.

In general though, currently I'm looking for a product that's able to handle 1000-100,000 rows with 10-100 columns. It'd be super cool if it could profile data sets, which is a feature Kettle sort of does, but not super well. I'd also like built in unit testing, meaning I'm able to build out control sets of data, and run changes made against the control set. Then I'd like to be able to selectively filter out rows and columns as I build out the transformation without altering the build; for example, I run a data set through transformation, filter the results, and the next run those sets are automatically blocked at the first "logical" occurrence; which in turn would mean less data to "look at" and a reduced runtime per each enhanced iteration; what would be crazy nice is if as I'd filtering out the rows/columns the app is tracking those, (and the output was filtered out). and unit tested/highlighted any changes. If I made a change that would effect the application logs and it's ability to track the unit tests based on me "breaking a branch" - it'd give me a warning, let me dump the data stored branch... and/or track the primary keys for difference in next generation of output, or even attempt to match them using fuzzy logic. And yes, I know this is a pipe dream, but hey, figured I'd ask, just in case there's something out there I've just never seen.

Feel free to comment, I'd be happy to answer any questions, or offer additional info.

Comment: Up to $1000?  How did you arrive at that number?  What products have you looked at?

Comment: @S.Lott: "Up to $1000? How did you arrive at that number?" Companies budget, really not interested in spending money though. I've looked at CloverELT; the CE has very little transformation support. In fact, seems like most ETL don't even do complex transformations. Haven't gotten to Talend, though the Java version appears to have 60-70% more transformations than the Perl version. Seems like to me most ETL focus on the E and L, not the T; though I'm complete new to this and mainly used Kapow/RoboSuite in the past for extracting data from the web; now I'm just focus on data transformation builds

Comment: @S.Lott : Here's a breakdown of the CloverETL's CE features, which they just posted: http://www.cloveretl.com/products/community-edition/features

Comment: Have you tried R (http://www.r-project.org/)? No GUI, though.

Comment: The comment on using the javascript step in Kettle is a positive thing!  The point is, there are lots of steps and transformations available to do probably 90-95% of things. BUT! if you have some unusual requirement, you can STILL do it in the javascript step. b.t.w. you can also use java, ruby, and openformula etc too.

Comment: @Codek: No, Kettle does not support common data transformations, and this is based both on using it and reading the most recent book by the guy who created it. Beyond that, why would I embed code in an IDE that's not an IDE for the code base I'm inserting into it? Meaning Kettle is not design to create, test, debug, maintain, etc JS code in my opinion.

Comment: Eh, it does. Take a look at sub mappings.  Is this what you mean by "common data transformations"?  I use them to great effect with a library of transformation snippets which i embed in various places.  Curiously named I must admit.

Comment: @Codek: Ok, I agree that my use of "common data transformations" is vague at best, though I don't agree that Kettle supports mapping/pipping/wiring them. Kettle has a even built-in (looking at "Pentaho Kettle Solutions", 2010; Matt Casters, one of the authors, is the founding coder of Kettle).

Comment: Kettle outsources most of the advance transformations to JavaScript, and the ones that are hard-coded into Kettle are hard to debug; in my opinion Kettle's killer feature is how fast it's execution time is without having to handcode Java/C++/etc. To me, something like a built-in IDE for regex coding/text/debugging that's easy to use would be an example of "common mods". Kettle to my knowledge has no IDE built-in for Javascript, but if it did and had a growing library of east to use well thought out snippets/functions, then I'd agree it supports "common mods".

Comment: Google Refine is okay at this, but it's not designed or intented to be use for production oriented data ETL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Google Refine](http://code.google.com/p/google-refine/)?

Comment: Very cool, thanks -- have you used it? Looks like it's just for niche tasks, but opensource and very good at what it does do; which is fine with me.

Comment: Yes, I've used it. It's very focused on cleaning up spreadsheets. I kind of think of it as a reimagining of Excel starting from the needs of tabular data, rather than empty grids.

Answer (score 2):

Talend will need more than 5 minutes of your time, perhaps closer to about 1 hour to begin to wire up a basic transformations and being able to fulfill your requirement to keep versioned control transformations as well.  You described a Pipeline process that can be done easily in Talend when you know how, where you have multiple inputs and outputs in a project as the same raw data goes through various transformations and filtering, until it arrives as final output as you desired.  Then you can schedule your jobs to repeat the process over similar data.  Go back and spend more time with Talend, and you'll succeed in what you need, I'm sure.

I also happen to be one of the committers of Google Refine and also use Talend in my daily work.  I actually sometimes model my transformations for Talend first in Google Refine.  (Sometimes even using Refine to perform cleanup on borked ETL transforms themselves! LOL ) I can tell you that my experience with Talend played a small part in a few of the features of Google Refine.  For instance, both Talend and Google Refine have the concept of an expression editor for your transformations (Talend goes down to Java language for this if need be).

Google Refine will never be an ETL tool, in the sense that we have not designed it to compete in that space were ETL is typically used for large data warehouse backend processing & transformations.  However, we designed Google Refine to compliment existing ETL tools like Talend by allowing easy live previewing to make informed decisions about your transformations and cleanup, and if your data isn't incredibly huge, then you might opt to perform what you need within Refine itself.

Comment: +1 @Thad Guidry: Thanks, I've in fact tried both of them. Don't recall much about Talend other than it has rerolled out two versions (Java/Perl) and each supports different functions. Google Refine is nice, and agree it'll never be an ETL, but does off the self fill in functional gaps that are present in Excel; for example native RegEx support. That said, while it's possible I missed it, or the feature has since been introduced, I recall Google Refine lacking an API or CLI. Thanks for posting, and really do believe Google Refine is an awesome tool.

Comment: @blunders There are 3 known APIs that are available: https://github.com/PaulMakepeace/refine-client-py/ 
https://github.com/maxogden/refine-python 
https://github.com/maxogden/refine-ruby

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what kind of data or exactly what kind of transformations you're trying to do, but if it's primarily mathematical transformation, perhaps you can try [FreeMat](http://freemat.sourceforge.net/), [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), or [SciLab](http://www.scilab.org/). If it's more data-warehouse-style munging, try open source ETL tools like [Clover](http://www.cloveretl.com/), [Talend](http://www.talend.com), [JasperETL](http://www.jaspersoft.com/jasperetl) Community Edition, or [Jitterbit](http://www.jitterbit.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, did download Talend-CE, but after 5-mins of "trying" to get it up, I gave up. I'll take a look at Clover, JasperETL-CE, and JitterBit right now. As for the mathematical transformation, it's currently not a need, but I'll still check out the apps, just so I have a rough feel for them. Again, thanks!